# bash sorting in a loop error

Tags: bash, sorting

I am trying to sort a bunch of files in a bash loop numerically (option -n) according to the second column (option -k 2):

```
for ch_perm in {0..99}; do
    for ch_set in {1..15}; do 
        sort -nk 2 $ch_perm.results.$ch_set > sortedbyscore2/$ch_perm.results.$ch_set ; 
    done
done
```

But the sort won't work correctly. Would anybody know? 
Thanks in advance!

This is the output I get:

```
for ch_perm in {0..99}; do
> for ch_set in {1..15}; do 
> 
Display all 1504 possibilities? (y or n)
11.results.21   13.results.35   15.results.49   3.results.61    5.results.74    7.results.88 [...]

>  -k 2 $ch_set.results.$ch_perm > sortedbyscore2/$ch_set.results.$ch_perm ; 
> done
> done
-bash: -k: command not found
-bash: -k: command not found
-bash: -k: command not found (many many times)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have used tabs to indent the script, which is then confusing bash when you paste it into the terminal, and you end up triggering bash's autocomplete with a double tab.  You can see that the "sort" has been lost when that happened.

Indent with spaces, or put this script in a file and run it from there.